# How to get only the path in the command "Git Submodule Status"

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and I'm trying to get all the paths of the submodules present.

Right now, when I execute the command `git submodule status`, I get the following output:

```
e1591f7ea63bcaaa7bee0b78b5dcf7754ea00410 main/abc (heads/master)
f61c2cd18e25228b681d516236b15eacc72363b6 xyz (heads/master)
```

Is there a way to get the output as a string like this:

```
 main/abc
 xyz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find an answer in the official documentation of Git, but failed to do so.

So I used [sed](https://ss64.com/bash/sed.html) to filter out the content what I need.

```
git submodule status | sed -e "s/^[+\ ][^\ ]*\ //" -e s/\ .*$//
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git submodule --quiet foreach --recursive pwd
```

`git submodule foreach` runs a command in an every submodule. `pwd` prints the current path. The disadvantage is the command prints the full paths.

```
git submodule foreach --recursive
```

prints `Entering '<path/to/submodule>'` for every submodule, relative paths.